# How to use parallel_for_each function and __declspec(dllexport) attribute at the same time

Tags: c++, dllexport, c++-amp

Recently I wrote a function like this:

```
#include "amp.h"
#define DLLExport __declspec(dllexport)
using namespace concurrency;

namespace dll
{
    class SomeMethods
    {
    public:
        static DLLExport double CalcConvolution(double* mask, double* map, int size)
        {
            array_view<const double, 1> avMask(size, mask);
            array_view<double, 1> avOMap(size, map);
            array_view<double, 1> avCache(size, new double[size]);
            avCache.discard_data();
            parallel_for_each(
                avCache.extent,
                [=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
            {
                avCache[idx] = avMask[idx] * avOMap[idx];
            }
            );
            avCache.synchronize();
            double sum = 0;
            auto cache = avCache.data();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                sum += cache[i];
            return sum;
        }
    };
}
```

Visual Studio reported the following error:

> error C1451: Failed to generate debug information when compiling the call graph for the concurrency::parallel_for_each

As soon as I removed the `DLLEXPORT` modifier, the error disappeared but I cannot export this function to my other programs any more.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2013 Professional and Windows 8.1 x64 now, and the code worked well before I upgrading my laptop from win7-64 and VS2012.

Comment: Hello.  This is an elusive issue that we have not been able to reproduce repetitively, and we'd be happy to help investigate it if you could provide us some more information.  Could you compile this program from the Visual Studio 2013 Command Prompt with the command `cl /Bv /EHsc /MD /LD /Zi test.cpp`?  If it repros, could you share (1) the compiler output when you run that command and (2) the result of running `set TEMP`?  You can either update the answer with this information, or feel free to contact me at james.mcnellis@microsoft.com.  Thank you!

Comment: @JamesMcNellis The problem seems to be solved, I successfully build target dll with the command you gave to me, However, I still cannot build the project in Visual Studio

Comment: @JamesMcNellis The things changed, last time I have wrongly input the command as    "cl /Bv /EHsc /MD /LD /Z test.cpp", which mistaken "/Zi" as "/Z", surprisingly, it works and successful builds up the target DLL, is that any help?

Answer (score 1):

We have observed error C1451 being reported when `TMP` environmental variable value contains non-ASCII characters. The temporary workaround is to set the user environmental variable to e.g. `C:\tmp`.

Comment: I am no expert but I don't see how this answer relates to the question. Try to be more specific.

Comment: Can you be more specific (no pun intended)? OP is observing error C1451 and the above answer provides valid and verified workaround to it. 
Did you have similar problem and it did not help?